# How to find whether any h1 heading exists in the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make the website that is not accessible as accessible , I am facing issues setting the headers in proper order. If there is any code that can be run on all the pages for setting h1 if h1 does not exist (h2 or h3 or h4 and so on can be made as h1 ) ,I would be really grateful. 
 If the h1 does not exist make the h2 as h1 or h3 as h1 or h4 as h1 and so on,if h1 exists exit the loop.

I tried to find h1 in the page but dont know what element that is common that I can take

website link is as follows https://www.opelika-al.gov/CivicAlerts.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Do you need `document.querySelectorAll` (or `document.querySelector`)?

You can easily determine if there are any `<h1>` tag on a page with this.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('h1'));
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
<h1>Bye bye</h1>
<footer>Copyright</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on a good accessible page you can simply zoom in.
If this is not enough you can provide buttons for zooming.
No need to modify html elements.